# How to set a limit for ridgidbodies speed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have been working on a game with cars but they go to infinite speeds, and that's not nice.

I have no idea how to do it I tried `rb.speed` and stuff but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After saving `rigidbody` and defining a variable for speed limit, just limit it with `Vector3.ClampMagnitude`.

```cs
public float maxVelocity;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    ///... Add force

    rb.velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(rb.velocity, maxVelocity);
}
```